# show spinner while loading new feeds

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do i show a spinner while waiting for news feeds to be loaded in ionic?

```
.controller('feedsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://example.com/feeds.php').success(function(data){
           $scope.feeds=console.log(data) ;
           $scope.feeds=data;

           $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 5; // Use it with limit to in ng-repeat
    $scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
        if ($scope.feeds.length > $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
            $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 5; // load number of more items
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete')
    }
```

HTML

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="addMoreItem()" distance="1%" 
 ng-if="feeds.length > numberOfItemsToDisplay">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: you can hide the feed view and show a div containing load screen until the callback from your request has completed and then show feed view again hiding loading screen in callback completion part of code.

Answer (score 0):

define a spinner like this in your html

```
<div ng-show="something">
        <img src="../../images/Splash_Screen_logo (2).png"  />

</div>
```

now in your js initially make it as false

```
$scope.something=false;
```

when everyou want to load  news feeds then change it to true

```
$scope.something=true;
```

after your data loading complete again assign it to false

Answer (score 0):

Your spinner directive (assuming you have one) should have a `ngShow`/`ngHide`/`ngIf` attached to a boolean variable preferably in a service, but could be in the `$scope` aswell (or with a `$scope.$on` event to get a broadcast from somewhere). Then you should toggle the variable to `true` before starting to load the feed and toggle it to `false` once it's been loaded.